# Procurar na coluna P por um valor > ou < e calcular esse valor na célula U?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Desde já quero agradecer ao @Leandro Felipe Moreira pela ajuda com o seguinte código:

```
Sub teste()

rng = Columns(16).End(xlDown).Row

MsgBox rng

For i = 1 To rng

    If Cells(i, 16).Value > "0" And Cells(i, 16).Value <= "100" Then

        Range("U2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+40%)"
        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & lastrow)
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value > "100" And Cells(i, 16).Value <= "150" Then

        Range("U2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+35%)"
        lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & lastrow)
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

O problema está no preenchimento até à última célula com:

```
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)
```

Pretendo que o cálculo seja feito na célula correta. Ou seja, procure na coluna P1 e apresente o cálculo na coluna U1 e sucessivamente.

Comment: Podes-me ajudar com este @Evert?

Comment: Olá amigo!  Ainda que marque com @NOME tanto em comentário ou numa pergunta/resposta o usuário não recebe essa notificação, salvo se já tiver participado de sua pergunta/resposta com um comentário.

Comment: Somente hj vi sua pergunta e que bom já ter encontrado sua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

RESPOSTA: **Cells(i, 26).Select**
Procurar na coluna P por um valor **superior**  ou **inferior** e calcular esse valor na célula Z?

```
Sub teste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

rng = Columns(16).End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To rng

    If Cells(i, 16).Value = 0 Then

        Cells(i, 26).Select
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 16).Value <= 50 Then

        Cells(i, 26).Select
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*1.7*(1+25%)"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value > 50 And Cells(i, 16).Value <= 100 Then

        Cells(i, 26).Select
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*1.7*(1+20%)"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value > 100 And Cells(i, 16).Value <= 200 Then

        Cells(i, 26).Select
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]*1.7*(1+15%)"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```